# Python Web Scraping on Designated folder and filename

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to python so any suggestion or example will definitely be beneficial for me.

I am scrapping a webpage to automatically download a CSV file just by clicking a button.

```
download= driver.find_element_by_id("fexpdistributiondetail")
exporttime = download.find_element_by_name('CSV').click()
time.sleep(3)
```

When this button is clicked, it automatically downloads and puts the downloaded file into my `downloads` folder on my PC.

I would like this file to be downloaded on:

1) different directory (say `desktop`)
2) rename the filename (currently is named as `distributiondetails.xls`). I would like it to rename as `distribution$(today date)` at `desktop` folder.

Comment: What is `driver`? Do you use any library?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("urlpath/stats/")
driver.maximize_window()